# Where are Serre’s lectures at Collège de France to be found?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ho.history-overview

Having run into several references, at various places and occasions, to "Serre’s Course at Collège de France, 19xy-19xy+1" for various values of xy, I would genuinely like to know where these lectures are written down and archived.

> Has there been an effort to preserve them in any form?

There are overviews of them in Serre’s collected work, but they have no references and don’t give full proofs.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the overviews that you have found so far? I do not personally know the answer, but it would be helpful for me since I would be able to search via keywords

Comment: I initially thought that $19xy-19xy+1$ referred to a polynomial, and was very confused.

Answer (score 21):

Most of my lectures have been taken down (hand written) and copies are available from Inst. Henri Poincaré. See Numdam CJP Serre.
JPS

Comment: Bienvenue à MathOverflow.

Answer (score 18):

The lecture notes for many of Serre's courses have been published:

- [Groupes algébriques et corps de classes](https://www.amazon.fr/Groupes-alg%C3%A9briques-classes-Troisi%C3%A8me-recherche/dp/2705612645) (transl. [Algebraic Groups and Class Fields](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387966489)) (Course at Collège de France 1956-1957)
- [Algèbre Locale, Multiplicités](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540070283) (Course at Collège de France 1957-1958)
- [Corps locaux](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000QA7ST0) (transl. [Local Fields](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387904245)) (Course at Collège de France 1958-1959)
- [Groupes proalgébriques](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1960__7__5_0/) (Course at Collège de France 1959-1960)
- [Cohomologie galoisienne](https://www.springer.com/jp/book/9783540580027) (transl. [Galois cohomology](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540421924)) (Course at Collège de France 1962-1963)
- [Arbres, amalgames](https://www.amazon.fr/Arbres-Amalgames-SL2-Serre-J-P/dp/B0043JZSQK) (transl. [Trees](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387904245)) (Course at Collège de France 1968-1969)
- [Lectures on the Mordell-Weil theorem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3663106349) (Course at Collège de France
  1980-1981)
- [Représentations linéaires des groupes finis](https://www.amazon.fr/Repr%C3%A9sentations-lin%C3%A9aires-groupes-finis-Jean-Pierre/dp/2705663525) (Course at École Normale
  1966)
- [Cours d'arithmétique](https://www.amazon.fr/Cours-darithm%C3%A9tique-%C3%A9dition-Jean-Pierre-Serre/dp/213041835X) (transl. [A course in arithmetic](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387900407)) (Course at École Normale 1962-1964)
- [Groupes finis](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503154) (transl. [Finite groups](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1571463275)) (Course at ENSJF, 1978-1979)
- [Topics in Galois theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814127) (Course at Harvard University 1988)

Comment: Don't forget 'Algebre locale' (1957 - 1958)!

Comment: Of course for a historical point of view it may be interesting to ask about preserved original versions of these (such as unrevised lectures notes written during the lectures).

Comment: There's this recent book about finite group theory by Serre

Comment: @CarloBeenakker it was Serre's lecture notes at ENS des Jeunes Files (or some variant plural form...) a basic version is available on arXiv and an expanded version is published

Comment: excellent, I have added it, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: It's not so important, but since you're also linking translations. The first item also exists in translation "Algebraic groups and class field theory", available from Springer.

Comment: thanks, link to translation added.

Answer (score 9):

The detailed abstracts (*résumés détaillés*) that are referenced are supposedly available in the "*Annuaire du Collège de France*". The [journal's website](https://journals.openedition.org/annuaire-cdf/450) unfortunately only contains newer entries (2005–). However, your library might have paper versions. According to [Mathdoc](http://cfp.mathdoc.fr/periodique/5148/), some physical versions are available in a few French libraries (notably at the IHP, the ENS, at the CIRM – with a few gaps in each case, unfortunately).

Some of the published versions that Carlo Beenakker mentions are available at [Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/). You can directly search for [Jean-Pierre Serre's works](http://www.numdam.org/search/%22serre,%20jean-pierre%22-a/). It might take some digging to know which lecture corresponds to which published paper, but the titles would probably help.