# Reference request: Serre's Groupes discrets

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, gr.group-theory

I'm reading some articles and at some point they both reference:

> J-P. Serre: Groupes discrets (in collaboration with H. Bass),
> Collège de France, 1969

However I have trouble finding this reference. Does anyone know how to obtain it.

According to [Carlo Beenakker](https://mathoverflow.net/a/328296/23501) these are lecture notes of a course that Serre thought, however the one I am interested in doesn't seem to be in Carlo's extensive list.

The main reason I am looking for these notes is that according to the text I am reading they contain a nice geometric explanation for the following.

Let $n,N$ be coprime integers. Define $\Gamma(N,\mathbb Z[1/n]) \subseteq \mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb Z[1/n])$ to be the matrices that reduce to the identity mod $N$. Let $p$ be a prime and define $$\Delta_N := \Gamma(N,\mathbb Z), \quad \Delta_N' := \begin{bmatrix}
p & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\Delta \begin{bmatrix}
p & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}, \Delta_N^0 := \Delta \cap \Delta'$$

**Proposition:** The inclusions of $\Delta_N, \Delta'_N$ and $\Delta^0_N$ in $\Gamma(N,\mathbb Z[1/p])$ make $\Gamma(N,\mathbb Z[1/p])$ isomorphic to the amalgamated product $\Delta_N*_{\Delta^0_N}\Delta'_N$.

So I would also be happy with any other work of Serre that contains the nice geometric argument for the above proposition.

Comment: In view of https://omekas.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/items/show/2121, it seems to me that this was subsequently included in Astérisque 46 ("Arbres amalgames $\mathrm{SL}_2$" by Serre), which in turn was published in English as the book "Trees".

Answer (score 5):

As [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437810/reference-request-serres-groupes-discrets#comment1128703_437810) by YCor these notes have been published as:

Serre, Jean-Pierre. Arbres, amalgames, $\operatorname{SL}_2$. Astérisque, no. 46 (1977), (red.), 198 pp.

Which is available for free through [the Numdam project](http://numdam.org/item/AST_1983__46__1_0).

The statement I was looking for is there with $N=1$ as corollary 2 on page 110.